# What the c++ class pointer size in 64bit machine code blocks compiler

Tags: c++

```
class node
{
public:
    int u;
    node* next;
    node() {};
    void setdata(int a) { u = a; };
    void setnext(node* nnext) { next = nnext; };
    int Data() { return u; };
    node* Next() { return next; };
};
```

I run this now via linux 64bit I found that size of class node is 16bytes ... 4 for int u, 8 for *next.... and remaining 4 bytes unknown, how can i identify or say size for each class elements

Comment: May it be that the compiler emits a 32-bit program where pointers are 32 bit?

Comment: check if your compiler is targeting a x64 platform

Comment: In my experience, the size of a pointer is the size of `size_t` - with very few exotic exceptions.

Comment: It would be either cross-compilation into 32bit binary, or you are using sizeof incorrectly. Can you post the sizeof code as well?